# How to extract json from json array [] of nifi objects?

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I have nested array:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "key_word": "бережливое производство\nканбан\nсокращение потерь"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "key_word": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "key_word": "healthy\nlearners\nlectures\nphysical education\nphysical fitness\nздоровье\nлекции\nобучающиеся\nфизическая культура\nфизическая подготовленность"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "key_word": "collective\nefficiency\ngroup\njoint activity\npsychological\nsocial\nsocial cohesion\nгруппа\nколлектив\nпсихологический\nсовместная деятельность\nсоциальная сплоченность\nсоциальный\nэффективность"
  }
]
```

how to divide this array into separate stream files for example:

```json
{
  "id" : 1,
  "key_word" : "бережливое производство\nканбан\nсокращение потерь"
}
-----------------------------------------------
{
  "id" : 2,
  "key_word" : ""
}
----------------------------------------------
```

I used `EvaluateJsonPath` with parameter JSONPath = `$.*`
and I used `SplitJson` with parameter JsonPath Expression= `$.*` and `$` don't work

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "key_word": "бережливое производство\nканбан\nсокращение потерь"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "key_word": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "key_word": "healthy\nlearners\nlectures\nphysical education\nphysical fitness\nздоровье\nлекции\nобучающиеся\nфизическая культура\nфизическая подготовленность"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "key_word": "collective\nefficiency\ngroup\njoint activity\npsychological\nsocial\nsocial cohesion\nгруппа\nколлектив\nпсихологический\nсовместная деятельность\nсоциальная сплоченность\nсоциальный\nэффективность"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use the `SplitJson` and apply the property JsonPath Expression to `$.*`

This will split the single large array in multiple JSON in this case 4 file fragments

[image: SplitJson]

[image: Flow]

You can see I got 4 outputs for the single input of the JSON array

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use JsonRecordReader and JsonRecordWriter with any of the record based processors.  This is the preferred method over splitting.  This also allows you to control the upstream schema, and downstream schema, as well as apply SQL-like query against those records.